# Westworld theme piano fingering question

Tags: piano, notation

I downloaded an app called MuseBook and I looked for sheet music for the Westworld theme. I found a couple and one seemed to be about my level so I've been studying it.

There is one section where I don't know what to do. The lines seem to overlap in weird ways. Here are three screenshots from my phone.

[image: screenshot-1]
[image: screenshot-2]

If you want you can also go to this link and have a look at the full PDF.

http://static.musescore.com/3105536/649dd8d12b/score.pdf

Measure 24 and 27 have the structure I'm unfamiliar with.

How do I play this? Why does it look like that?

Comment: It looks like that because whoever created it didn't know what they were doing. The staves are too close together, and the leger lines overlap. But if you sort that out, a computer can play things that humans can't reach! I suggest you keep looking till you find a better version.

Comment: @alephzero If you sort out the overlapping leger lines, it is very reachable, IMO. The seemingly three top notes on the first beat of the first screenshot are actually two Ds an octave apart which you can play with your right hand and the top note of the left hand on the first beat of the second screenshot is the same A as is in the right hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that because it's a awful transcription. In fact, it looks suspiciously like the result of a MIDI-to-score transformation.

I'd suggest either finding a better transcription, or editing it yourself to make it playable. The easy way to do that would be to drop the higher notes in the left hand entirely, and just keep the lowest octave (two notes).

Note that you might need to pay to get a decent version. Some of the transcriptions that float around on the internet can be of questionable accuracy. Of course, that might not matter. At the end of the day, if you're having fun and playing music, who really cares?

Comment: Thanks endorph. Yeah, I'm having fun playing it. I think you're right about the "MIDI-to-score transformation". I'll follow your suggestion with dropping the higher notes.